# Simplify, $\sqrt[3]{3}\bigg(\sqrt[3]{\frac{4}{9}}-\sqrt[3]\frac{2}{9}+ \sqrt[3]\frac{1}{9}\bigg)^{-1}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

> Simplify, $\sqrt[3]{3}\bigg(\sqrt[3]{\frac{4}{9}}-\sqrt[3]\frac{2}{9}+ \sqrt[3]\frac{1}{9}\bigg)^{-1}$.

**What I have tried:** Put $x = \frac{1}{9}$. We have, $\sqrt[3]3\big(4x^\frac{1}{3} - 2x^\frac{1}{3} +  x^\frac{1}{3})$
$$\rightarrow \sqrt[3]3\big(x^\frac{1}{3}(4-2+1)\big)$$
$$\rightarrow \sqrt[3]3 \times \frac{1}{3\sqrt[3]x}$$
$$\rightarrow \frac{3}{27x} = \frac{1}{9x}$$
Putting back the value of $x$ gives the answer to be $1$.

However, in my text the answer is given to be $\sqrt[3]2 + 1$ , so where did I go wrong?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your first line is wrong how did you get $4x^{(1/3)}+2x^{1/3}$

Comment: Why? Because we are taking the cube root.

Comment: i fail to see how $$\sqrt[3]{4/9}=4x^{1/3}$$

Comment: Oh, I think the mistake went to $4x^\frac{1}{3}$ instead of $(4x)^\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

: $$\sqrt[3]{4/9}-\sqrt[3]{2/9}+\sqrt[3]{1/9}=\frac{(2^{1/3}+1)(2^{2/3}-2^{1/3}+1)}{(2^{1/3}+1)(3^{2/3})}=\frac{3}{3^{2/3}(2^{1/3}+1)}$$ so:$$\sqrt[3]{3}\bigg(\sqrt[3]{\frac{4}{9}}-\sqrt[3]\frac{2}{9}+ \sqrt[3]\frac{1}{9}\bigg)^{-1}=\sqrt[3]{3}\cdot \frac{(2^{1/3}+1)(3^{2/3})}{3}=\sqrt[3]{2}+1$$

Comment: Ok I am getting it, then do we cube the fraction?

Comment: @Anonymous no,no take the reciprocal and multiply with $\sqrt[3]{3}$

Comment: Ok, then I suppose we will get $\frac{√3}{\sqrt[3]2 + 1}$.

Comment: @Anonymous edited

Comment: Oh nevermind, I feel a little stupid sometimes, I got it.